# Is it possible to pass data from AWS Lambda to java program sitting in Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-fargate

Since AWS Lambda has 15 min timeout, we are working on creating a long time running program similar to Lambda. For this, we decided to use AWS Lambda, ECS Fargate and ECR which hosts a Docker image.

```
Flow: S3 PUT event ----> Lambda ---> ECS Fargate ---> Run Docker Container
```

Since Lambda is being triggered by a S3 event, Lambda Handler method would be called with S3Event and Context parameters. Now, I need to access S3Event and Context data from the java program sitting in the Docker image. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While it would be possible to do this, ECS/Fargate is generally intended for long-running applications.

I believe that a better solution is [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html), which allows you to queue jobs and start concurrent containers to process those jobs. When a job is finished, the container shuts down. Depending on how you configure the environment, the underlying EC2 instance can remain running or shut down as well.

You would predefine your batch job and submissionn queue, and design your Java application to take all of the information that it needs as command-line parameters. Then you use a Lambda function like this:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
batchClient = boto3.client('batch')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for rec in event["Records"]:
        s3_bucket = rec["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        s3_key = rec["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        print("processing s3://" + s3_bucket + "/" + s3_key)

        # see https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job
        response = batchClient.submit_job(
                    jobName='lambda-invocation-example',
                    jobQueue='first-run-job-queue',
                    jobDefinition='first-run-job-definition',
                    parameters={
                        's3_bucket': s3_bucket,
                        's3_key': s3_key
                    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Lambda can connect to docker the way any other code would connect to docker. Lambda can discover the docker service using service discovery and then fetch the data from docker.

Comment: Thanks @deosha, But I am not trying to get the data from Docker, I need to pass data from Lambda to the docker image.

Comment: So you mean docker should be able to connect to lambda and not vice versa Is lambda throwing data to docker or docker polling data from lambda?